# Using GoPhish API in Powershell to Launch Campaigns

Tags: powershell, api

currently i'm attempting to setup GoPhish to launch campaigns through a Windows PowerShell script using it's API. The issue that i'm running into that is i'm getting this error.

```
Invoke-WebRequest : { "message": "Invalid JSON structure", "success": false, "data": null }
```

The thing is I have triple checked my JSON structure and it doesn't show any errors in JSON formatting checkers. So my question is if there are any errors in the code I have below for actually pushing these campaigns via PowerShell.

```
$jsonString = @"
{
   "name":"Test6",
   "template":{
      "name":"Test"
   },
   "url":"http://redacted",
   "page":{
      "name":"Test"
   },
   "smtp":{
      "name":"Test SMTP"
   },
   "launch_date":"2019-25-07T08:20:00+00:00",
   "send_by_date":null,
   "groups":{
      "name":"Test Group"
   }
}
"@

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://redacted/api/campaigns/?api_key=redacted -Method POST -Body $jsonString
```

So if you see any errors in what I have an could help me out, that'd be awesome. The API documentation shows that it should be in this format

```
{
    "name":"CC Example Campaign",
    "template":{"name":"Example Template"},
    "url":"http://localhost",
    "page":{"name":"Example Landing Page"},
    "smtp":{"name":"Example Sending Profile"},
    "launch_date":"2018-10-08T16:20:00+00:00",
    "send_by_date":null,
    "groups":[{"name":"Example Group"}]
}
```

Comment: There may not be anything physically wrong with the JSON message, but the error message can also mean that the *structure* of the message that the API is *expecting* is incorrect (e.g. missing or extra fields). I would double check the API documentation.

Comment: Ah thanks, I appreciate it, i'll definitely look into if there's more I need to add.